# Differential equation problem seperable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After solving the differential equation below, I get $y^{2}=2(x\log x-x) + c$

What is the value of c?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
0<\left| y'\right| < \infty 
$$
thus
$$
y(1)y'(1) = \ln(1) = 0 \implies y(1) = 0
$$
since the derivative does not vanish at $x=1$ we conclude that $y(1) = 0$ this can yield a result on $C$.